# monacaで作ったアプリのキーボード設定について

Tags: android, monaca

monacaでAndroidアプリを作る練習をしています。まずはとサンプルのメモアプリをカスタマイズすることから始めたのですが、実機デバッグやデバッグビルドしたアプリをスマホで動かす際、キーボードが必ず英語キーボードになり日本語が選択できません。
この現象は何が原因で起こるものなのでしょうか？どうやったら直すことができるのでしょうか？
どうかよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

以下のどちらかが原因ではないでしょうか。

1. 英語入力のみのキーボードを使用している
2. 英語しか入力できない入力フィールドに入力しようとしている
   例：`type`属性に`password`を指定
   `<input name="title" ng-model="title" type="password" placeholder="タイトル"></input>`